# WPF some letter bigger then other letters in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, fonts

I use Nunito font in my WPF application and when font size set up for 12 units i get text like this

[image: https://i.imgur.com/677I9J5.png]

You can see that the a N letter is bigger than other (there is also some other letters have this kind an error)

Here's the style of my TextBlock:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="text-secondary-base">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource nunito-regular}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="LineHeight" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
</Style>
```

Is there's the way to fix that without increasing FontSize?

Comment: Is this affected by `UseLayoutRounding="True"`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Setting FontSize to 12.1 fixes it (12.09 doesn't). I can only imagine that there's an error or corner case in the rasterization hints (note that there are known limits to my imagination). There's a feedback link in the lower right corner of that Nunito page on Google Fonts.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, this fixed the error. Thanks!